# Unable to load navigation property of an entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-data-services

When I run the following code, the last line

```
repository.Context.LoadProperty(userPatient.Patient.Practice, "Enterprise")
```

throws an exception

> The context is not currently tracking the entity

How can I load the navigation property `Enterprise`? I am not sure what I am missing. Please help.

```
public class QuickLaunch
{
        private UserPatient userPatient = null;
        private PortalRepository repository = null;

        public QuickLaunch(PortalRepository repository)
        {
            this.repository = repository;
            userPatient = MySession.Current.SelectedPatient;
            repository.Context.LoadProperty(userPatient.Patient.Practice, "Enterprise");
        }
}
```

Comment: Is that `repository.Context.MergeOption` setting exists? If yes, try setting it to `MergeOptions.AppendOnly` before using `LoadProperty`, or if no, try finding `MergeOption` setting in your context somewhere.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - I tried your suggestion, but still getting same exception. This is what I added.  `repository.Context.MergeOption = System.Data.Services.Client.MergeOption.AppendOnly;
            //repository.Context.AttachTo("UserPatient", UserPatient);
            repository.Context.LoadProperty(userPatient.Patient.Practice, "Enterprise");`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do have an alternative solution to this problem.  I can add that particular context to session variable.  Then when I need to load a navigation property using that context, I can always use the context I saved in session.  I tried it and it works.  But I am not sure if that is correct or best way to do it.